# Problem with external monitor (mini DP)

Tags: 16.04, hdmi, thinkpad, external-monitor, displayport

1)
After upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 the system couldn't find my external monitor, wich is connected to the mini DisplayPort via a HDMI-adapter.

When I go back to kernel-version 4.2.0-23, it detects the monitor. A later kernel-version won't work. Why is that?? Is it smart to use an old version?

2)
Another 'problem' when I use the external monitor is that it's flickering when doing some tasks, like watching Youtube etc...

3)
When connecting/disconnecting the external monitor (using the old kernel), nothing happens before I open the System Settings. How can I make it go automatic? You know, when connecting the monitor the system only display the built-in display and the external monitor is black. Once I open the System Settings, I can use both screens. Same when I disconnect the external monitor, the system operates like I still use dual-screen, but once I open System Settings everything shows up in the built-in display.